# How to disable click events for props.children in React?

Tags: reactjs

How can any click events be disabled for `props.children`?

```
const Example = props => (
  <div>
    <div>This can be clicked</div>
    {props.children} /* These can't be clicked */
  </div>
)
```

I am rendering a PDF page using [react-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf) and want the user to be able to drag a custom selection marquee (like in Photoshop...). As it is, the PDF page under or inside the marquee element still registers mouse events upon dragging, like text selection.

Comment: Can you show some code that we can compile and run ourselves?

Answer (score 5):

There is an easy, but not robust way to do this:

```
const Example = props => (
  <div style={{pointerEvents:'none'}}>
    <div style={{pointerEvents:'auto'}}>This can be clicked</div>
    {props.children}
  </div>
)
```

It is not robust, because if any of the children have `pointer-events` set to `auto`, they will be clickable too. See if it fits your needs. Also, it will kill `hover` and other mouse events.

Comment: Could [`React.Children`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren) be used to set `pointer-events`, maybe in conjunction with [`React.cloneElement`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement)?

Comment: @JackSteam Don't know, but children of children also can have `pointer-events` set, so it wouldn't help.

Answer (score 1):

## Use CSS Grid to put a `div` on top!

A transparent `div` rendered on top of another `div` will intercept click events.

CSS Grid can be used (abused?) to make a single grid area (using `grid-template-areas`) and assign multiple elements to it (using `grid-area`).

**JSX**

```
const ClickGuard = ({allow, block}) => (
  <div className='click-guard-area'>
    <div className='click-guard-allowed'>{props.allow}</div>
    <div className='click-guard-block' />
    <div className='click-guard-blocked'>{props.block}</div>
  </div>
)
```

**CSS**

```
.click-guard-area {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 'click-guard';
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.click-guard-allowed {
  grid-area: click-guard;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.click-guard-block {
  grid-area: click-guard;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

.click-guard-blocked {
  grid-area: click-guard;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Note that ClickGuard expects two props: `allow` and `block`. These should be JSX. [The React docs explain passing React elements here.](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#containment)

```
<ClickGuard
   allow={<div>I can be clicked!</div>}
   block={<div>No clicks for me. </div>}
/>
```

Comment: What is your use case for this?

Comment: @trixn I added my use case to the question just now.

Comment: Okay but i still don‘t see why this requires the click events to be prevented. This seems like solving a problem that comes through not picking the correct design in the first place.

Comment: Great! I like this approach. I used this to make a component to wrap editable elements, to disable some of them according to user's permissions. Although there is one disadvantage - user can delete blocking element inside devtools.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the props within an element thus its children props.
An alternative solution may be possible with [React.cloneElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement),
Here is a simple peace of code for you:

```html
const Example = props => (
  <div>
    <div>This can be clicked</div>
    {props.children.map((child)=>
        React.cloneElement(child, {
          disabled: true
        })
    )}
  </div>
)
```

Comment: This looks promising, but does `disabled` work on elements other than form elements (`button`, `input`, `fieldset`, etc...)? [W3C HTML disabled Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_disabled.asp)